# ANTLR decision warning

Tags: eclipse, antlr

I have written the following grammar. I want to write expressions x+2; x/2;...

```
grammar HASKELL;

options {
  language = Java;
}

program
    : statment+
    ;

statment
    :declaration
    | expression
    ;

declaration
    : typeDecl
    ;

typeDecl
    :numType 
    |listType
    ;

type
    : 'num'
    | 'list'    
    ;


numType
    : type IDENT '=' INTEGER ';' 
    ;


listType
    :type IDENT '='  '[' INTEGER* ']'  ';'
    ;   

term                    
    : IDENT
    | '(' expression ')'
    |   INTEGER
    ;

negation
    : 'not'* term
    ;

unary
    :  ('+' | '-')* negation
    ;

mult
    : unary (('*' | '/' | 'mod') unary) *
    ;   

add  
    : mult (('+' | '-') mult)*
    ;

relation        
    : add (('=' |'/='|'<'|'<='|'>'|'>=') add)*
    ;

expression
    :   relation (('and' | 'or') relation)*
    ;

MULTILINE_COMMENT : '/*' .* '*/' {$channel = HIDDEN;} ;
fragment LETTER : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z') ;
fragment DIGIT : '0'..'9';
INTEGER : DIGIT+ ;
IDENT : LETTER (LETTER | DIGIT)*;
WS : (' ' | '\t' | '\n' | '\r' | '\f')+ {$channel = HIDDEN;};
COMMENT : '//' .* ('\n'|'\r') {$channel = HIDDEN;};
```

which produces the following warning:

```
(200): Decision can match input such as "'+'..'-' IDENT" using multiple 
       alternatives: 1,2 As a result, alternative(s) 2 were disabled for 
       that input   HASKELL.g   Assignment2/src/com/assignment2/antlr3x/first    
       line 59 DLTK Problem
```

I can't see the confusion caused by the add. I tried to remove ('+' | '-')* under unary and it worked. But don't want to exclude stuff like x+(-2). Any ideas how to do it by not removing ('+' | '-')*
Thanks

Comment: I meant the one in the error "multiple alternative"

Comment: Ah, I didn't see you put the warning inside your grammar. I took the liberty to move it outside the grammar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your grammar is ambiguous because of these rules:

```
program
    : statment+
    ;

statment
    : declaration
    | expression
    ;
```

I.e.: you allow for multiple `expression`s without a delimiting token, like a `;` or a line break. Because of that, input like this:

```
1+2
```

could be parsed in multiple parses:

```
statment
  |
  +--> expression --> INTEGER (1)
  |
  +--> expression --> unary (+2)
```

or like this:

```
statment
  |
  +--> expression --> add (1+2)
```

You can verify this by removing the `+` from your `program` rule:

```
program
    : statment
    ;
```

which causes the warning to disappear.